# Magento - URL Rewrite not working

Tags: magento, url-rewriting

In magento i am trying to add in a url redirect in the admin system so I can bypass a category page to go straight to the product as there is only 1 product in that category. In the `Catalog => URL Rewrite Management` section i have the following entered:

```
Type - Custom
ID Path - category/15
Request Path - labels
Target Path - labels/a4.html
Redirect - Yes
```

But when i go to the `labels` page it doesn't redirect. I know that it definetly has a category ID of 15 and that the labels/a4.html is correct

Comment: if it is not going to the required page then to which page it is going??

Comment: ok sorry my mistake the category labels is a subcategory of `stationary` when i added that in front it now gives the following error: magento Request Path for Specified Store already exists and checking there is a system redirect on the labels path that was added automatically. How can i add this other one as well?